# $2^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}.$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

[image]

---

The question is asking to show that $q$ must be prime given
$$ 2^{q-1}\equiv 1\pmod{q}. $$

Comment: No, it can't be asking that.  Look at the second sentence.  You need not only to consider $2^{q-1} \mod q$, but also $2^k \mod q$ for $1 < k < q-1$.

Comment: $\overset{?}{p\cdot(1-\frac{1}{p})}$

Comment: The group of units mod $n$ has size $\phi(n)$. Hence the order of every element divides $\phi(n)$. So in this case $(q-1)\mid\phi(q)$. Is that possible if $q$ is composite? (Hint: if $n$ is composite, show that there is more than one number $\le n$ that is not coprime to $n$, hence $\phi(n)<n-1$ when $n$ is composite.) For the second part of the question, check to see that the *order* of $2$ in the example is actually a *proper* divisor of $340$.

Answer (score 2):

If $q=2n$ where $n$ is odd, $\phi(q)=\phi(2)\phi(n)=\phi(n)<n$

$q-1=2n-1$ will be $>n$ if $n>1$

So, for $n>1, \text{ord}_q2<q-1$

Else if $q= m\cdot n$ where $(m,n)=1$  where $m>n>2$

Using Euler's [Totient Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersTotientTheorem.html), $2^{\phi(n)}\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $2^{\phi(m)}\equiv 1\pmod m$

$$\implies 2^{\text{lcm}(\phi(n),\phi(m))}\equiv1\pmod {lcm(m,n)}$$

and lcm$(m,n)=m\cdot n=q$

As $\phi(n),\phi(m)$are both even for $m,n>2, 2$ divides $(\phi(n),\phi(m))$

$\implies \text{lcm}(\phi(n),\phi(m))< \phi(n)\cdot \phi(m)=\phi(q)$

So, $\text{ord}_q2<\phi(q)\le q-1$

So, a necessary condition for $\text{ord}_q2=q-1$ is $q$ must be prime

Now we know if $\text{ord}_q2=d$ and $2^r\equiv1\pmod q, d$ must divide $r$

As $341=11\cdot31$

$2^2\equiv4,2^5\equiv-1\pmod {11}\implies \text{ord}_{11}2=10 $

and $2^5\equiv1\pmod {31}\implies \text{ord}_{31}2=5 $

$\implies \text{ord}_{(11\cdot31)}2=$lcm$(5,10)=10$ which successfully divides $340$ which eventually turns out to be $341-1$

Comment: We know $(n-1)^2\equiv1\pmod n\implies (n-1)^{2r}\equiv1\pmod n$ for integer $r$ and if we set $n=2r+1, (n-1)^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$ but $n=2r+1$ is not necessarily prime.

Comment: See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CarmichaelNumber.html

Answer (score 1):

This the counter example of converse of FERMAT'S theorem,

For converse we have to show that if $a^{p-1} \equiv1\pmod p  $ then p must be prime.

Note that $341=31\cdot11$

By Fermat's theorem,

$2^{10} \equiv1\pmod {11}$

$2^{30} \equiv1\pmod{11}$

$2^{31} \equiv2\pmod {11}$

$2^{(31)(11)} \equiv2^{11}\pmod{11}\big(\because a\equiv b\pmod{n} \ \text{then} \ a^n \equiv b^n\pmod{n} \big)$

$2^{341}\equiv2\pmod {11}$($\because$ By Fermat's theorem)

Also,

$2^{10} \equiv1024\pmod{31}$

$2^{10} \equiv1\pmod{31}$

$2^{11} \equiv2\pmod{31}$

$2^{(11)(31)} \equiv2^{31}\pmod{31}$

$2^{341}\equiv2\pmod {31}$($\because$ By Fermat's theorem)

Since gcd$(11,31)=1$

$\big(\text{Here i used the result If} \ \ a \equiv b\pmod{n_1} and \ \ a \equiv b\pmod{n_2} \text{and gcd} \ \ (n_1,n_2)=1 \text{then}  \ \ \  a \equiv b\pmod{n_1\cdot n_2} \big)$

$2^{341} \equiv2\pmod{11\cdot 31}$

$2^{341} \equiv2\pmod{341}$

But $341$ is not a prime number.

Comment: Who started $a.b$ to mean $a\times b$ or $a\cdot b$?

Comment: @BarisaBarukh see the edited ans.

Comment: @Siddhant: I'm fairly sure that Barisa is protesting against your use of a period **on the baseline** as a multiplication sign. I also find it strange, because a period there means a full stop = end of sentence. A centered dot produced by TeX-code `\cdot` is used between numbers formed by strings of digits, and between numbers presented by symbols multiplication is implies without inserting anything in between. So I would use $31\cdot11$ and $n_1n_2$.

Comment: ok.i shall edit it.the dot'.' denote multiplication.

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just wondering where it started; that is, historically.

Comment: @BarisaBarukh thanks'.' this dot is full stop not multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

If the order of the prime (ie its period) is $p-1$ or half of that, it means that power of 2 up to $2^{p-1}$ is a different value, mod $p$, and hence there are $p-1$ numbers between $0$ and $p$ that share no common factor with $p$.  Thence $p$ is a prime.

The case for numbers like $31$ and $73$ is that the order *divides* $p-1$, rather than being it.  This means that the powers of $2$ do not cycle through all of the roots of $p$, and hence one can not demonstrate that $p$ is coprime to all $0<n<p$.

In the case of $341$, the indicated period is $10$, which means that it can at most visit $10$ of the available co-primes to $341$.  In the main, the use of testing primes in this way is usually efficient, but there are classes of number, $1299936601 = 601 \cdot 1201 \cdot 1801$ has a period of $3600$ in any base under 601, which makes it appears prime.  It is in fact what is called a **pseudoprime**.  Any given base can have more pseudoprimes than the general populus.  For example, $2^{11}-1$ is a pseudoprime to base 2, since both the primes that divide this ($23, 89$), both have 11-digit periods in base 2.